# Haskell parse error when using DataBase.Persist (possibly related to use of quasi quotes)

Tags: haskell, persistent

I've taken part of the code from http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent (Synopsis section) and am trying to load it into ghci (v7.6.3, running on Ubuntu 14.04).

```hs
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] 
[persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]
```

When loading this into ghci, I get the following error:

```
Prelude> :load "/home/gautham/tmp/Test.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/gautham/tmp/Test.hs, interpreted )

/home/gautham/tmp/Test.hs:7:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

which is the line starting with 'Person'. Any idea what might be causing this? I've looked at several examples on the web and have tried several variations of indentations, but haven't been able to get this to compile. I assume it has something to do with incorrectly using the quasi quotes, but I'm not sure what?

Cheers
Gautham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the language pragmas suggested in the tutorial as well? In other words, does your source file begin with

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
```

All of them might not be needed, but you can figure out which ones are unneeded by removing one at a time until you have a minimal set that still compiles.

Comment: Thanks! I'd seen other code samples without those pragmas and assumed they were just comments. It's not compiling yet, but it's moved forward from the parse error. I'll try experimenting with selectively enabling these once I get it compiling.

Comment: @GauthamGanapathy They use the same format as comments, but they are indeed special directives that tell GHC to enable the corresponding extension. You don't need to have them in your source file, but then you have to tell GHC which extensions to use through command-line flags.

Comment: Just wanted to note that `{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}` was what i was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable a lot of language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
```

In addition, the `[persistLowerCase| ... |]` must either begin on the same line as the `share` or be a bit indented since it is the second parameter to `share`. So, you might get:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    [persistLowerCase|
    Person
        name String
        age Int Maybe
        deriving Show
    BlogPost
        title String
        authorId PersonId
        deriving Show
    |]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out these pragmas. I did try indenting the [persistLowerCase|...|] section, but it didn't work at the time, maybe from the missing pragmas.